# The argument type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<bool> Function()?'

Tags: flutter

i need to program the back arrow on the device, but this error occurs.

**the code of WillPopScope:**
body: WillPopScope(
onWillPop: back(context), => error
),

**back function is:**

```
Future<bool> back(BuildContext context) async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 onWillPop: back(context),
```

to

```
onWillPop: () async => await back(context),
```

Comment: it works but why this occurs?
what means by the type 'Future<bool> Function()?'
@Hemal

Comment: `onWillPop` is returning `WillPopCallback?`, Which is typedef of `'Future<bool> Function()?`. It's used to create a user-defined identity (alias) for a function. In this scenario you can no directly use your future function.

Comment: when i used this unction as a member of this class it called directly, but when i make it as a global in a separate file the problem occurred, @Hemal

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirnment you will click on back arrow and go to the previous screen so try below code hope it help to you.

```
IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
    ),
```

Comment: i need to do both of them

Comment: what do you want explain in brief

Comment: sometimes you need to program back arrow because when the language of the device is from right to left you will need to program it manually .
 the solution is answered by another person, thanks for helping me :) @Ravindra S. Patil